# How to make list tag as selected or active by default on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-sref

I am using `ui-sref-active="active"` to make the selected `<li>` tag active but I want a list tag to be active as default out of three list tags

```
<li ui-sref-active="active" class="item active"><a data-ng-click="search.status = ''" href="">ALL PROJECTS</a></li>
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a data-ng-click="search.status = 'PORTFOLIO'" href="">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a data-ng-click="search.status = 'CATEGORY'" href="">NOTIFICATIONS</a></li>
```

I want the first list tag to be active by default and then when user clicks on anyother list tag it should deactivate and activate other list tag

I am using this directive: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ng-class to dynamically turn class 'active' on and off.

```
<li ui-sref-active="active" ng-class="{active: activeTab1}"><a data-ng-click="search.status = ''" href="">ALL PROJECTS</a></li>
<li ui-sref-active="active" ng-class="{active: activeTab2}"><a data-ng-click="search.status = 'PORTFOLIO'" href="">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
<li ui-sref-active="active" ng-class="{active: activeTab3}"><a data-ng-click="search.status = 'CATEGORY'" href="">NOTIFICATIONS</a></li>
```

In your controller you can switch the activeTab1,2 and 3 on and off based on which list tag the user clicks. You can set activeTab1 true by default.

UPDATED

added {} in ng-class because of the syntax

Here is a working example in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2X1mEbZjKgkGH3EGZFCe?p=preview)

Comment: set activeTab1 true by default.?? set it in controller you mean?

Comment: I didn't understand how it works in controller. Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: I updated my answer and added a working example in Plunker.